# Serving static Resource with spring boot + spring security

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, gulp

I work on angularjs application and I try to serve static resource (my front end) with Spring boot.

I used gulp to build project and I get this distribution structure:
[image]

- here is the content of **hash** folder

[image]

my spring security config look like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(myEntryPoint());
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/__hash__/**").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/views/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll(); 

    http    // login configuration
            .addFilterAfter(springSecurityFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

    /*http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();*/

    http    //logout configuration
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler());

    http.csrf().disable();

}
```

The config spring for serving static content:

```
@Configuration
public class MyContentConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:///" + "c:/front/") ;
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}

}
```

After authentication, I get the index.html page but without css style and without js.

[image]

And when I try to access to css using this url "[https://localhost:9999/**hash**/styles.min.css](https://localhost:9999/__hash__/styles.min.css)" I get this error:

```
 There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
 Could not find acceptable representation
```

Comment: you are using **HTTPS** to access you server ressources .. do you have a valid **SSL** configuration in your **.properties** file  ?

Comment: Yes. I have configured tomcat to use SSL

Comment: did you try using **HTTP** ?

Answer (score 2):

You are loading **livereload.js** over **http**. If you are using https, all resource must be load over https.
so **load livereload.js over https**.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. it's related to "spring-cloud-config-server". I just delete this config:
      
            org.springframework.cloud
            spring-cloud-config-server